# According to Catholicism, why do we worship Christ?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, christology, worship

According to the Catholic understanding of Christology, Worship and the Trinity; would it be accurate to state that we worship Jesus because He is the Person who is the 2nd Person of the Trinity? Stated differently, we worship the Personality of Jesus because that Person is God (the 2nd Person of the Trinity); and not necessarily because He is the God-Man.

That God became Man and wrought our Salvation is a reason to worship God, and by extension, Jesus.

Background: I'm a Catholic and I was thinking about this, but wasn't sure if it would separate the Divinity from Jesus. I came up with this understanding while trying to figure out how to respond to someone who suggests that we worship a human. In the plain sense, I want to say Yes we do- but not because He is human, but because He as a Person is God who simply became incarnate. I wanted to see if this was a sound understanding of why we worship Jesus.

Comment: This is a great question,compounded even more when you consider that not only do we worship Our Lord after he takes on Human flesh, but also, as he takes on with that same divine Nature, the outward  form of bread and wine. I am inclined to post a complete answer here when I have time but in the meantime I would entertain to you that the Creator of heaven and earth and all that being such encompasses,choosing to take the form of man is a far greater requirment for faith, then that same man taking on the form of Bread and Wine. Adoration for the Eucharist and of Christ is one and the same.

Comment: Marc, now that IS food for thought! [to Others:I saw this question was down voted earlier; could the one who down voted it provide a reason? If clarification or re-wording is necessary, I'd be happy to oblige.]

Comment: @shiningcartoonist I didn't downvote, but I'd start by making the title an actual question. Maybe try rewording the first paragraph a bit. Try formatting with bullets maybe. The title and the sort of wobbly wording of the first paragraph kept me from upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Jesus is our creator is the main reason why we worship Him.

> "Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honour and power: **for
>   thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were
>   created**" (Rev 4:11)
>
> "Fear God, and give glory to him; for the hour of his judgment is
>   come: **and worship him that made heaven, and earth, and the sea, and
>   the fountains of waters.**" (Rev 14:7)
>
> "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the
>   Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God. **All things
>   were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was
>   made**." (John 1:1-3)

The fact that He chose to take on our nature and save us is a demonstration of His infinite love and makes us even more capable of rendering Him worship.

Comment: While this answer is most certainly true on all accounts, I am looking for an answer that is more focused on the Nature of the 2nd person of the Trinity- or maybe a more Christologically focused answer. That being said, your answer would certainly be reasons to worship God Himself, including the 2nd Person.

Comment: @shiningcartoonist I might be mistaken, but I believe that we worship God, not any individual Person separately. To worship one, *is* to worship the other two. I'd have to look into this, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: This answer would benefit from citing Catholic sources.

Comment: @Nathaniel For Catholics, the Bible is a Catholic source.